# Symfony How to get only selected Bound variables from number of tokens?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, token

I am developing an application in Symfony2 and new to the framework.
I have a variable **$params which contains begdate, enddate, extzoneid and ulevel**. 
I am only interested in fetching the extZoneId, begdate and enddate and not ulevel. In other words, I only want to select particular parameters and not all. I want to enhance the resuability of the code. How to get only selected Bound variables from number of tokens?

Executing this will throw the 'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' Error because my number of bound variables do not match the number of tokens. Here is my functions

```
 public function ReportQuery($params)
     {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TestBundle:Report');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('t');

    $qb->select('t.extUserId, t.userName, t.extZoneId, t.zoneName, sum(t.nbCnx) as nbCnx')
         ->where($qb->expr()->between('t.loadDate', ':begDate' , ':endDate'),
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->in('t.extZoneId', ':zones')
            )
        )
        ->addGroupBy('t.extUserId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.userName')
        ->addGroupBy('t.extZoneId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.zoneName')
        ->orderBy('t.userName', 'ASC')
        ->setParameters($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should force parameters entry to avoid this error, like :

```
public function ReportQuery($begDate, $endDate, array $zones)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TestBundle:Report');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('t');

    $qb->select('t.extUserId, t.userName, t.extZoneId, t.zoneName, sum(t.nbCnx) as nbCnx')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->between('t.loadDate', ':begDate' , ':endDate'),
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->in('t.extZoneId', ':zones')
            )
        )
        ->addGroupBy('t.extUserId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.userName')
        ->addGroupBy('t.extZoneId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.zoneName')
        ->orderBy('t.userName', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('begDate', $begDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
        ->setParameter('zones', $zones);
}
```

Or if you want something more dynamic :

```
public function ReportQuery(array $params)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TestBundle:Report');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('t');

    $qb->select('t.extUserId, t.userName, t.extZoneId, t.zoneName, sum(t.nbCnx) as nbCnx');
    $qb->where('1 = 1'); // to call andWhere after...

    if (isset($params['begdate']) && isset($params['enddate'])) {
        $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->between('t.loadDate', ':begDate' , ':endDate')
        );
        $qb->setParameter('begDate', $params['begdate'])
           ->setParameter('endDate', $params['enddate']);
    }

    if (isset($params['zones']) && is_array($params['zones'])) {
        $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->in('t.extZoneId', ':zones')
        );
        $qb->setParameter('begDate', $params['zones']);
    }

    $qb
        ->addGroupBy('t.extUserId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.userName')
        ->addGroupBy('t.extZoneId')
        ->addGroupBy('t.zoneName')
        ->orderBy('t.userName', 'ASC');
}
```

I personnaly prefere the first method.